# Is there a weight limit to Feather Fall?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I was curious if there's a weight limit to *feather fall* in either spell or enchanted item.

From what I've read there isn't, but I'm not sure if it'd be up to the DM's discretion or if there is/was a limit like in earlier editions.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No, spells don't have limits unless they are stated

[*Feather fall*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feather-fall)'s description is:

> Choose up to five falling creatures within range. A falling creature’s
>   rate of descent slows to 60 feet per round until the spell ends. If
>   the creature lands before the spell ends, it takes no falling damage
>   and can land on its feet, and the spell ends for that creature.

This spell does not say anything about a weight limit, so we can assume that there is none. If it is a creature, and is within 60 ft. of you, and you have the components, (and nothing is preventing you from doing this), you can cast feather fall on it regardless of its weight.

Comment: You can featherfall five falling terrasques if you like. No weight limits.

Comment: How many meters per second is 60 feet per round?

Comment: @Mazura a round is 6 seconds, so 60ft./6 seconds, so 10 ft./second, which in meters per second is about 3.04 meters / second.

Comment: TIL feet/seconds it about the same as km/h. 10ft/second is about 11 km/h which is probably easier to visualise for most

Comment: A good thing for a druid who's currently a mammoth.

Answer (score 9):

## Nope, it works all the time*

*[Feather fall](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feather-fall)* has no limitations beyond the casting requirements for range (60'), material, and verbal components. As long as those are met, then it'll work.

*It won't work if they are in antimagic field, or if one of the requirements listed above isn't meant. Or if it's not a creature.